# Is this proof reasoning that every real symmetric matrix has a real eigenvalue correct?

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

"Every real symmetric matrix has a real eigenvalue"

For an n by n symmetric matrix over R, we simply assume that we are working with C (the field of complex numbers). And since every matrix over the complex number has an eigenvalue, and it is also a proven theorem that every symmetric matrix over C is real, can we conclude that our n by n matrix over R has a real eigenvalue?

Comment: What do you mean by "every symmetric matrix over C is real"?

Answer (score 0):

No, there is no logic in that. You are saying *all objects from $A$ (symmetric complex matrices) have a certain property $B$ (real), hence all objects with property $A$ and $B$ (i.e. real symmetric) has property $C$ (real eigenvalues)*.